# PDO Select query inside a while loop when uploading files it not excuting

Tags: php, pdo

I am running this PHP PDO code to upload a file and then in the while loop it is running a select query ising PDO:

```
if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['dd_submission_form']['tmp_name'])) {
        echo "<h3>" . "File ". $_FILES['dd_submission_form']['name'] ." uploaded successfully." . "</h3>";
    }

    //Import uploaded file to Database
    $handle = fopen($_FILES['dd_submission_form']['tmp_name'], "r");

    fgetcsv($handle);

    while(($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        if($data[5] == '17') {

            echo '<strong>DD Ref: </strong>'.$data[0].'<br>';

            $stmt = $pdo_conn->prepare("SELECT * from customer where directdebit_reference = :directdebit_reference ");
            $stmt->execute(array(':directdebit_reference' => $data[0]));
            $customer = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            if(count($customer) > 0) {

                echo '<h3>'.$customer["company"].'</h3>';

            }
        }
    }
```

but it doesn't seem to be selecting any rows within the while loop

i know that rows defiantly exist as when i run a query in PHPMyAdmin it returns rows

If i run this MySQL PHP query:

```
$sql="SELECT * from customer where directdebit_reference = '".$data[0]."' ";
rs=mysql_query($sql,$conn);
$result=mysql_fetch_array($rs);
echo $result["company"];
```

it echoes the company column fine

Comment: You should to see what [errorinfo()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.errorinfo.php) returns.  There might be an error that you aren't taking into account.

Comment: i have tried doing echo $stmt->errorCode(); after my execute command but nothing shows. my connection string looks like: $pdo_conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbname', 'username', 'password', array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));

Comment: I think you should read the documentation for [`PDOStatement::fetchAll()`](http://php.net/manual/pdostatement.fetchall.php). Pay close attention to the return value. You should also enable proper error reporting. If you had, you would be informed of the problem (undefined index *"company"*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the `fetchAll` method. It'll load all the fetched results of your query as a nested array. Therefore, for the first customer's data, you'd need:

```
echo '<h3>'.$customer[0]["company"].'</h3>';
```

Alternatively, you can update to:

```
$customer = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Or, better yet, just limit the results to one.

```
$stmt = $pdo_conn->prepare("SELECT *
    FROM customer 
    WHERE directdebit_reference = :directdebit_reference
    LIMIT 1");
$stmt->execute(array(':directdebit_reference' => $data[0]));
$customer = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```